# What character do we have to use for Datetime and Integer type in python to connect with MySql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to take input using python code

This is the structure of my mysql table

```
 | Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| datetime   | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| close      | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| high       | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| low        | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| open       | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| volume     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| instrument | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I enter the code `query = """INSERT INTO orders (datetime, close, high, low, open, vloume, instrument) VALUES (%, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %, %s)""`"`

Can anybody help me by suggesting what letter should i give in % to take datetime and integer input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I believe that you want it to all be a string. Datetimes will be strings, so the formatter you would use is %s. That being said, datetimes need to be formatted in a very specific pattern to be accepted in mysql. Make sure you read up on that, otherwise you won't be able to index the date. %d is the formatting string for integers, I believe.

The length of int doesn't matter to python, so it only needs to know an integer will be there

tl;dr

datetime: %s

int: %d